# Problema ao fazer uma chamada de método no construtor de classe (javascript)

Tags: javascript, método, construtor

Estou aprendendo javascript e estou recebendo o seguinte erro: *setTitulo is not defined*

Por que este erro acontece? O método setTitulo não deveria estar definido já que pertence a classe?

```
class Nota{
    constructor(titulo, descricao){
        try {
            this.titulo = setTitulo(titulo);
            this.descricao = descricao;            
        } catch (error) {
            showError(error);
        }        
    }

    setTitulo(titulo){
        if(titulo !== null && titulo.length > 0)
            return titulo;
        else
            throw new Error("title", "Title is sadsadsa");        
    }  

}



class Error{
    constructor(name, message){
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }    
}

const showError = function(error){
    const panelError = document.getElementById("panel-attention");
    panelError.innerHTML = `Error: ${error.message}`;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `this.setTitulo(titulo);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o @augusto-vasques comentou, se está acessando um membro da própria classe, deve usar o `this`.

Pra entender melhor, vou até usar seu exemplo, no método `setTitulo`. Supostamente pelo nome, ele deveria setar o "titulo", mas não está fazendo isso. Se alterar para ele fazer isso, vai ter um conflito com "titulo":

```
setTitulo(titulo){
        if(titulo !== null && titulo.length > 0) {
            titulo = titulo;  //aqui está o problema
            return titulo;
        }
        else
            throw new Error("title", "Title is sadsadsa");        
    }
```

Veja que, para passar o valor recebido no parâmetro "titulo" para o membro interno "titulo" que foi definido no contrutor, precisa usar `this.titulo = titulo`. Da mesma forma, precisa usar para informar que é um membro da própria classe, senão o interpretador do `javascript` vai buscar fora da classe, e como não existe, no caso do seu erro, `setTitulo`, dá esse erro.

Veja o código alterado:

```js
class Nota{
   
    constructor(titulo, descricao){
        try {
            this.titulo = this.setTitulo(titulo);
            this.descricao = descricao;            
        } catch (error) {
            showError(error);
        }        
    }

    setTitulo(titulo){
        if(titulo !== null && titulo.length > 0) {
            this.titulo = titulo;
            return titulo;
        }
        else
            throw new Error("title", "Title is sadsadsa");        
    }  
    
    getTitulo() {
      return this.titulo;
    }

}

class Error{
    constructor(name, message){
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
    }    
}

const showError = function(error){
    const panelError = document.getElementById("panel-attention");
    panelError.innerHTML = `Error: ${error.message}`;
}

var nota = new Nota("tit", "descr");
console.log(nota.getTitulo());
nota.setTitulo("Titulo alterado");
console.log(nota.getTitulo());
nota.setTitulo("");
```

```html
<div id="panel-attention"></div>
```

Comment: Aparentemente há um problema, setTitulo é um método de atribuição e retorna `undefined`, então não deveria ser `this.titulo = this.setTitulo(titulo);`. Deveria ser somente `this.setTitulo(titulo);`.

Comment: sim, como estava usando o `setTitulo` para setar a propriedade, faltava o return, obrigado por comentar ;)